# need to explode tags to array in php language

Tags: php, arrays, tags, explode

I have my tags in line:

```
word1 word2 word3 "word4 word1" word4 "word7 word4" "word67 word56 word1" word7
```

need to get everything in array like:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4 word1
word4
word7 word4
word67 word56 word1
word7
```

need to do it with explode(" ",$input) and explode("\"",$input) combination, or something else, but i have no idea how..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is to use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-getcsv.php)

Example :

```
var_dump( str_getcsv('word1 word2 word3 "word4 word1" word4 "word7 word4" "word67 word56 word1" word7', ' ', '"'));
```

Comment: at the beginning, CSV is only a comma separated value string, in your case the comma is replaced by the space, that's all ;)

Comment: @Jay, str_getcsv is meant for parsing CSV rows as a string. Etienne just used it for this application instead. Very clever

Comment: I've tested this function in many tag variations, it's perfect what i've been looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `preg_match_all()`. An Example for you

```
$str = 'word1 word2 word3 "word4 word1" word4 "word7 word4" "word67 word56 word1" word7';
preg_match_all('/(word\d)|("([^"]*)")/', $str, $m);

print '<pre>';
print_r($m[0]);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go down the preg_split route, you could so explode(" \"", $input), and then go through that output, and where the array item doesn't have a trailing ", split that by space.  Where it does have the trailing ", remove it.

It's not an elegant solution, but would work.

```
$round1 = explode(" \"", $input); // split based on the " at the start
$round2 = array();
foreach ($round1 as $word) {
    if (substr($word,-1) == "\"") {
        $round2[] = str_replace("\"","",$word); // get rid of the trailing "
    }
    else {
      // need to merge our existing array with the exploded array
      $round2 = array_merge($round2, explode(" ", $word);
    }
}
```